# How to find the positions of the N biggest values of a list in python?

Tags: python, list

I am trying to find the N biggest values from a list, and then print out their positions in the list.

If I would only focus on the max. value, it would look like this:

```
>>>>fr = [8,4,1,1,12]
>>>>print fr.index(max(fr))
4
```

However, my aim is to get an output like: `4,0,1` if it were for n=3. The `0` here shows the position of the second biggest value. REMEMBER, I am not interested in the value, but in their position!

Comment: Where is `0` in input?

Comment: 0 shows the position of the second biggest values... REMEMBER, I am not interested in the value, but in their PoSiTiOn! :-) Thanks!

Comment: @thefourtheye `0` is the position of the `2nd` largest number in the list.

Answer (score 24):

Use [`heapq.nlargest`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/heapq.html#heapq.nlargest) with key = `fr.__getitem__`:

```
>>> import heapq
>>> fr = [8,4,1,1,12]
>>> heapq.nlargest(3, xrange(len(fr)), key=fr.__getitem__)
[4, 0, 1]
```

If you want the values itself, then:

```
>>> heapq.nlargest(3, fr)
[12, 8, 4]
```

Comment: nice! That is exactly what I needed! You mind though explaining how it works? Thanks!

Comment: @user3604362 It sorts the indices `xrange(len(fr))` based on the key i.e the value at those indices in `fr`, and return the 3 largest value. It is not exactly sorting but using heapq algorithm to get the largest items.

Answer (score 8):

Another way is:

```
[fr.index(x) for x in sorted(fr, reverse=True)[:3]]
```

When we compare speed of both of them...

```
import heapq

fr = [8, 4, 1, 1, 12]


def method_one():
    for i in xrange(10000):
        res = [fr.index(x) for x in sorted(fr, reverse=True)[:3]]


def method_two():
    for i in xrange(10000):
        heapq.nlargest(3, xrange(len(fr)), key=fr.__getitem__)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    import timeit

    print timeit.repeat(stmt='method_one()',
                    setup='from __main__ import method_one',
                    number=100)
    print timeit.repeat(stmt='method_two()',
                    setup='from __main__ import method_two',
                    number=100)
```

we get:

```
[1.1253619194030762, 1.1268768310546875, 1.128382921218872]
[2.5129621028900146, 2.529547929763794, 2.492828130722046]
```

Comment: of course you're not going to see the O(n log(n)) behaviour of sort with just 5 items. sheesh

Comment: I don't think it stops at the largest 3 numbers, instead it lists all indices. `[fr.index(x) for x in sorted(fr, reverse=True)][:3]`, whereas this will get the first 3 elements.

Comment: Note that this does not work where the list may contain duplicate elements. Take `fr = [8,8,1,2,12]` and n = 4, then `result=[4, 0, 0, 3]` which may not be what the OP asked for. The heap solution gives the correct `[4,0,1,3]` indices though

Answer (score 4):

This simplest way is to just do this

```
>>> fr = [8,4,1,1,12]
>>> n = 3
>>> result = [fr.index(i) for i in sorted(fr, reverse=True)][:n]
>>> print(result)
[4, 0, 1]
```

No libraries and dependancies.

Answer (score 1):

it's always easy to convert the list to numpy array and deal with it.

```
import numpy as np

arr = np.array([10, 5, 8, 15, 15, 12])

sorted_indices = np.argsort(arr)[::-1]
largest_indices = sorted_indices[:3]
print(largest_indices)
```

Output: [4 3 5]

Answer (score 0):

```
select = 4    
list_val = [5.0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 5.0]
result = [list_val.index(i) for i in sorted(list_val, reverse=True)][:select]
print(result)
    
#expected: [0, 5, 1, 2]
#output: [0, 0, 1, 1]
```

This method won't always work.

Answer (score -1):

The simplest possible way is -

```
  In[0]: import numpy as np
    ...: a = [1,4,2,5]
    ...: a.remove(sorted(a)[-1])
    ...: np.argmax(a)
 Out[0]: 1
```