# How do I find the location of the second largest number in a list? (Python)

Tags: python, list

My first ever question on here!
The following line of codes asks if the largest number in the list seat_votes is located in position 0.

```
if seat_votes.index(max(seat_votes)) == 0:
```

Is there an easy way to ask this but for the second largest number in a list?

I'm thinking something similar to the large funtion on excel. So at a guess the code would look like the following.

```
if seat_votes.index(large,2,(seat_votes)) == 0:
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to find position of the second maximum of a list in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23473723/how-to-find-position-of-the-second-maximum-of-a-list-in-python)

Comment: `max(enumerate(seat_votes), key=itemgetter(1))` will return tuple of index and value of max element in list. Imports: [`itemgetter()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html#operator.itemgetter).

Comment: Python has a `sort` function, or just use `max` again on the remaining seats after eliminating the largest value from the list.

Comment: @OlvinRoght - That's a good technique for max and index, but it's not really addressing the question.

Answer (score 0):

I will make the assumption that the list has at least two elements.

You can use the sorted function as suggested by others :

```
if sorted(seat_votes)[-2] == seat_votes[0]:
```

But if the maximum value is present multiple times in the input, it still considers the maximum value.

If you want to the second biggest unique, you can use sets :

```
if sorted(set(seat_votes))[-2] == seat_votes[0]:
```